# remove an open WiFi of a service provider near my house

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Windows 7. There is an access point of a service provider WiFi near my house. The WiFi is not free and not WEB/WPA protected. Everyone can connect to it and it will show the company's login page. (if the username/password are put correctly, their customer can use the net.)

I'm not the customer of the company and have my own access point in my house. But my computer always connect to the network of that company. I tried to remove the network but it keep coming back and connect to that access point instead of mine.

What can I do to make my computer choose my access point first?

Comment: Related: [How can I ignore a particular Wifi network?](http://superuser.com/questions/352165/how-can-i-ignore-a-particular-wifi-network) which was closed as a dupe of [Optimizing wireless router speed and minimizing interference](http://superuser.com/questions/57912/optimizing-wireless-router-speed-and-minimizing-interference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Manage Wireless Networks, select the network you don't want to connect to, and click "Move Down" until it is at the bottom of your priority list. Then, right click it, select Properties, and uncheck "Connect automatically when this network is in range."

Answer (score 4):

Click the WiFi icon in the task bar, then choose "Open Network and Sharing Center".

On the left side of the window that opens, choose "Manage wireless networks".

Find the WiFi network that you keep connecting to unintentionally, and remove it by selecting and clicking the "remove" button.

Your computer should no longer connect to the other access point now.

Comment: The other access point keeps coming back.

Comment: @wannik what do you mean by "coming back"? Is it automatically connecting or just showing up? You can't make it not show up in the list at all.

Comment: It will always show up in the list of available networks. If you remove the auto-connect profile, your computer should not attempt to connect to it by itself.

Answer (score 1):

1) Choose a unique network name for your network.

2) Delete any configuration profile you have for this other access point.

3) Use some kind of encryption mode for your access point.